# GWT: client/server condition compilation

Tags: gwt, client-server

Is it possible in GWT to have a different implementation of a function on the client and on the server? E. g.

```
private static native String toFixedNative(int digits, double value) /*-{
    return value.toFixed(digits);
}-*/;

public static String toFixed(int digits, double value) {
    if (GWT.isClient()) {
        return toFixedNative(digits, value);
    } else {
        String format = "%." + digits + "f";
        return String.format(Locale.US, format, value);
    }
}
```

This doesn't work currently, GWT compiler complains, that `String.format` function is not available in GWT. But it is not really needed, because `String.format` is called only when `!GWT.isClient()`.

Is there any way to tell GWT compiler to ignore a part of the function?

Answer (score 1):

With a recent version of GWT (2.7, maybe also 2.6), it should be possible to do that by moving the `String.format` into a method that you then annotate with `@GwtIncompatible` (any annotation with that name would work, package doesn't matter).

In any version of GWT, it's also possible to *super source* a class: provide two versions of a class for client and non-client cases. See “Overriding one package implementation with another” in http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModuleXml
You'll find plenty of examples in GWT itself; this is also how the Java Runtime is emulated.

Comment: `@GwtIncompatible` doesn't work: if I wrap `String.format` as `@GwtIncompatible formatWrapper()`, GWT compiler just doesn't see `formatWrapper` method, and thus still complains about it in `toFixed`.